# How can I combine fixed month and day with sql year function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, text

I want to compose a date in `T-SQL` with a fixed day and month (always the last day and month of the year), the year must be variable.

- the day is always: `31`
- the month is always: `12`
- the year is variable, let's say `2014`

The format would be like `12-31-2014` or `12-31-2015`.

I have the `YEAR` function in mind:

```
select '12'+YEAR(getdate())-1
```

but this results in `2014+12=2026`.

How can I achieve this with T-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has the `DATEFROMPARTS` function for this purpose:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = DATEFROMPARTS( 2014, 12, 31 )
```

Documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx

Comment: Thanks a million Dai!

This function has the following syntax: DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )

For me worked: select DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(getdate())-1, 12, 31)

Result: 2014-12-31

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that `YEAR()` returns a number so the server is adding instead of concatenating. So, if you want to do it with concatenation, you'll need to force that number back into a CHAR(), and then recast the whole concatenated mess back into a DATE (assuming you want a date type returned):

```
select CAST('12-31-'+CAST(YEAR(getdate())-1 AS CHAR(4)) as DATE)
```

That being said @Dai's answer using `select DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate())-1, 12, 31)` is a little bit easier on the eyes, and probably the CPU.